# Pumping Lemma for Regular Language seems to Fail

Tags: regular-languages, pumping-lemma

Let $L = \{ab^ncd \mid n \geq 0\}$.  If we take $p = 5$ and $w = abbcd$ and write 
$w_i = xy^iz$, where $x = abb$, $y=c$, $z=d$, then $w_2 = abbccd$ which is not in $L$.  We conclude that $L$ is not regular but it obviously is!

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pumping lemma says that *there exists* a decomposition of $w$ to $xyz$ such that $y$ can be pumped.

It doesn't say that *for all* decompositions of $w$ to $xyz$, $y$ can be pumped.

In your example, a possible decomposition is:

$x=a$

$y=bb$

$z=cd$

Comment: Pumping lemma isn't an iff. It holds for some non regular languages, but always holds for a regular language.

Comment: @AswinAlagappan in your example, pumping $y$ even once will give: $aababb$, which is not in $L$.